# Tree representation of Entity-Relationship in Python using NLTK

Tags: python, tree, nlp, nltk, entity-relationship

My aim is to extract entity relationship from a text file. I don't know much how the output should be. I took the input (aaa.txt):

> My school situated in Kolkata. The color of the sky is pink. I wonder why?

and got the output:

```
(S
  My/PRON
  (NP school/NOUN)
  situated/VERB
  in/ADP
  (NP Kolkata/NOUN)
  ./.
  (NP The/DET color/NOUN)
  of/ADP
  (NP the/DET sky/NOUN)
  is/VERB
  (NP pink/NOUN)
  ./.
  I/PRON
  wonder/VERB
  why/ADV
  ?/.)
```

Is it completely correct? These kinds of problems are not very clear to me, as I am a beginner in both Python and NLTK, and could not find any good clarification from Google. Can the output be presented in a better format (Tree, Tabular etc.) ?

Comment: Yes. NER works this way. What other information do you wish to extract ?

Comment: Thanks. Can the output be presented in a better form?

Comment: Can you define what would be better?

Comment: I mean how to remove the tags.??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract list of Persons and Organizations using Stanford NER Tagger in NLTK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664677/extract-list-of-persons-and-organizations-using-stanford-ner-tagger-in-nltk)

Comment: How to present this entity relationship in tabular format?