# NLTK Convert Tree to Array?

Tags: python, list, tree, nltk, python-3.4

To start with I turned the tree into a list:
You insert an already tokenized sentence and it returns a tree.

```
def LanguageCreateTree(tokenizedSentence):
    cp = nltk.RegexpParser(GRAMMAR)
    result = cp.parse(tokenizedSentence)
    result = str(result)
    print(result)

>>> A red cat with a hat
(S A/DT (VP red/VBN (NP cat/NN)) with/IN a/DT hat/JJ)
```

How would I go about to make a list with lists in it based on this string?
I need it to be able to make a list like this:

```
[['A','DT'], ['VP', ['red','VBN'], ['NP', ['cat','NN']]], ['with','IN'], ['a','DT'], ['hat','JJ']]]
```

Comment: Is it possible to start from the tree instead of going to a string and then back to basically a tree?

Comment: Also isn't your parsed list missing the `'S'` designator at the beginning?

Comment: The output you describe is still a tree; a list containing other lists etc recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a lot easier than you think :-) The NLTK's `Tree` class *is* a list (more specifically, it is derived from the list class). And it has exactly the structure you are after. Just use ordinary list methods on the result of `cp.parse()`. Here's an approximate example (building a tree on the fly for illustration):

```
>>> from nltk import Tree
>>> t = Tree.fromstring("(S A/DT (VP red/VBN (NP cat/NN)) with/IN a/DT hat/JJ)")

>>> print(t[1])
(VP red/VBN (NP cat/NN))
>>> print(t[1][0])   # Element 0 of the subtree at index 1
red/VBN
```

In this example I did not split the word from the POS tag; your tree will look different. Also note that `Tree` has nice ways of printing itself, but you can see the real structure by using `repr()`:

```
>>> print(repr(t[1]))
Tree('VP', ['red/VBN', Tree('NP', ['cat/NN'])])
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a good solution. But how would I go about separating the "A/DT"s then? So that they become two different list items too.

Comment: In your own tree, there shouldn't be anything to separate: words and POS tags are separate, this is just how they're printed. Try it, and provide a short but complete (executable!) example if you can't get it to work.

Comment: If I just skip what you told me to do and just use result[x] It works with "A/DT" and it shows it as a list like so: ('A','DT').

Comment: No, **now** you're doing what I told you to do: "Just use ordinary list methods on the result of `cp.parse()`". You hadn't understood me before, my example is just for illustration since your code is incomplete. [In the code you give in your question, `result` is a string so what you say is impossible; but I'm sure your real code is different).

Comment: But glad you got it to work. If my answer has resolved your problem, please "accept" it by clicking on the big check mark next to it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. This is my first time posting here so I'll try to be more clear next time. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: No prob! But incomplete questions are harder to answer, as you can see. Welcome to stackoverflow, by the way :-)

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to convert my cp.parse to array structure.Pls take look at my question. This is not the answer by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702150/python-re-write-the-text-with-its-proper-nouns-chunked

Comment: @Arda, if it's the same problem, use the same solution! But actually the answer to your question is "use a Named Entity Recognizer". I don't understand why you keep saying it isn't. If you want to do this for Turkish, train a NER. Anyway your question was marked a duplicate (corretly, in my opinion). If you're sure it isn't, you must edit it and explain why not, and ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: Also see this answer (also by me) to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30665014/699305

Comment: Dear Mr @alexis trust me i don't want waste anybody's time. I really searched and tried the answers. Let me explain why i should'nt use ner tagger; my graduation project is creating my own NER for turkish with my own searching methods(i created sets , fucntions which gives me the person org and locs). All i want is making the cp.parse output an two dimensional array. I searched the book and could'nt remove the tags ı really feel sorry about that. I'm struggling to figure out how can i only print the [[Rami Eid],[Stony Brook University],[NY]] without any pos or ner tagger.

Comment: Basically i want to only use nltk for only count proper nouns as one array member.So sorry for very long comment i didnt want to create same question for many time.Feel free to tell me anything i did wrong and tell me what to do.Also thank you again for reply.

Comment: I'm afraid "I couldn't get it to work" is not a question anyone can answer. And look: grouping capitalized words is not the way to write a NER; if I were your teacher I'd fail you if that was your project. Train an NER for Turkish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109896/discussion-between-alexis-and-arda-nalbant).