# Extracting the person names in the named entity recognition in NLP using Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I have a sentence for which i need to identify the Person names alone:

For example:

```
sentence = "Larry Page is an American business magnate and computer scientist who is the co-founder of Google, alongside Sergey Brin"
```

I have used the below code to identify the NERs.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
print(ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))))
```

The output i received was:

```
(S
  (PERSON Larry/NNP)
  (ORGANIZATION Page/NNP)
  is/VBZ
  an/DT
  (GPE American/JJ)
  business/NN
  magnate/NN
  and/CC
  computer/NN
  scientist/NN
  who/WP
  is/VBZ
  the/DT
  co-founder/NN
  of/IN
  (GPE Google/NNP)
  ,/,
  alongside/RB
  (PERSON Sergey/NNP Brin/NNP))
```

I want to extract all the person names, such as

```
Larry Page
Sergey Brin
```

In order to achieve this, I refereed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664677/extract-list-of-persons-and-organizations-using-stanford-ner-tagger-in-nltk) and tried this.

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordNERTagger
st = StanfordNERTagger('/usr/share/stanford-ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz','/usr/share/stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar')
```

However i continue to get this error:

```
LookupError: Could not find stanford-ner.jar jar file at /usr/share/stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar
```

Where can i download this file?

As informed above, the result that i am expecting in the form of list or dictionary is :

```
Larry Page
Sergey Brin
```

Comment: StanfordNERTaggger has one g too many.

Comment: @rainer - Thank you so much. I will edit the error now which i am getting

Comment: @DoubtDhanabalu You have to download the jar from https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html#Download and provide that path in StanfordNERTagger

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## In Long

Please read these **carefully**:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49345866/610569
- [Extract list of Persons and Organizations using Stanford NER Tagger in NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664677/extract-list-of-persons-and-organizations-using-stanford-ner-tagger-in-nltk)

Understand the solution, don't just copy and paste.

---

## TL;DR

In terminal:

```
pip install -U nltk

wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip
unzip stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31.zip && cd stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31

java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer \
-preload tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,depparse \
-status_port 9000 -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

In Python

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import CoreNLPNERTagger

def get_continuous_chunks(tagged_sent):
    continuous_chunk = []
    current_chunk = []

    for token, tag in tagged_sent:
        if tag != "O":
            current_chunk.append((token, tag))
        else:
            if current_chunk: # if the current chunk is not empty
                continuous_chunk.append(current_chunk)
                current_chunk = []
    # Flush the final current_chunk into the continuous_chunk, if any.
    if current_chunk:
        continuous_chunk.append(current_chunk)
    return continuous_chunk


stner = CoreNLPNERTagger()
tagged_sent = stner.tag('Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY'.split())

named_entities = get_continuous_chunks(tagged_sent)
named_entities_str_tag = [(" ".join([token for token, tag in ne]), ne[0][1]) for ne in named_entities]


print(named_entities_str_tag)
```

[out]:

```
[('Rami Eid', 'PERSON'), ('Stony Brook University', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('NY', 'LOCATION')]
```

You might find this help too: [Unpacking a list / tuple of pairs into two lists / tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558908/unpacking-a-list-tuple-of-pairs-into-two-lists-tuples)

Comment: Which version is this?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'CoreNLPNERTagger' from 'nltk.tag.stanford' (/home/akshatz/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.py)

Answer (score 0):

In the first place you need to download the jar files and the rest of the necessary files. Follow the link : https://gist.github.com/troyane/c9355a3103ea08679baf. 
Run the code to download the files(except the last few line). Once done with the downloading part you are now ready to do the extraction part.

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordNERTagger
st = StanfordNERTagger('/home/saheli/Downloads/my_project/stanford-ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
                   '/home/saheli/Downloads/my_project/stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar')
```