# Replacing nouns from 2 strings

Tags: python, string, replace, named-entity-recognition

Is there Anyway I can replace nouns from one strings to another. Like I have 2 strings

e.g.

> original = "his name is Javed Aaqib.He lives in Karachi"
>
> gen = " They call him Aab Khan. His residence is in Karachi."

Now here I want to replace **fake noun (Aab Khan)** with **original noun (Javed Aaqib)**
i.e. after replacing gen should be **"They call him Javed Aaqib"**

I have extracted Named Entities using spacy but stuck in logic how to match the fake names them as there are multiple nouns in text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387699/extracting-the-person-names-in-the-named-entity-recognition-in-nlp-using-python) in the best response  as part of your solution.

At the end of the code on link above add:

```
person_names = filter(lambda x: 'PERSON' in x[1], named_entities_str_tag)
print(person_names)
```

person_names will be a list of persons name on the sentence, in your case it'll be only one, for you to replace with the desired one.

Comment: actually i dont have a signal name i have vast variety of name, its basically from news so can be anything. btw I have used spacy to extract name entities then applied some logics in case of multiple names