# NLTK: Extract the entity name from a string

Tags: python, nltk

Python and NLTK noob here. Messing around with something.

I have a string which contains text from a pdf document and I'm trying to extract entity names using the nltk library

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    str_output = f.readlines()   

str_output = clean_str(str(str_output))

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(str_output)
tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)
```

I went through the steps of importing the data, cleaning the string, and preprocessing the strings. How does one go about getting different entity names from the string?

Comment: You're iterating through the sentence multiple times. Don't do that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30666949/610569

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import nltk

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    sample = f.read()

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(sample)
tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)

def extract_entity_names(t):
    entity_names = []

    if hasattr(t, 'node') and t.node:
        if t.node == 'NE':
            entity_names.append(' '.join([child[0] for child in t]))
        else:
            for child in t:
                entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(child))

    return entity_names

entity_names = []
for tree in chunked_sentences:
    # Print results per sentence
    # print extract_entity_names(tree)

    entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(tree))

# Print all entity names
#print entity_names

# Print unique entity names
print set(entity_names)
```

Comment: Don't encourage the questioner by reusing the code that iterates through the data multiple times.